# Dell E6420 (laptop) 14" LCD monitor Windows 7 driver

Tags: windows-7, laptop, drivers, display, dell-latitude

I have a Dell E6420 (laptop) in company. The Windows device manager uses "Generic PnP Monitor" for the 14" LCD monitor. It only has 1600x900, 1024x768, 800x600, while I was looking for a 1366x768. Google search for Windows 7 driver didn't get any luck. I did find a cab ([link](http://en.community.dell.com/techcenter/enterprise-client/w/wiki/latitude-e6420-windows-7-driver-cab.aspx)), but it seems like not include the monitor driver. Does anyone know where to find the monitor driver? I just need more resolution options.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The dell support page has windows 7 video drivers for the E6420 at [this page.](http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19) or better - go to the Dell support page and enter your service tag (sticker on the bottom of your laptop). There are a few options depending on which LCD panel you have installed and if you are running 32 or 64 bit windows.

Comment: this is really good resource for drivers. However, it doesn't include LCD driver. Is there other places that I can find LCD driver? Thanks.

Comment: The LCD panel is physically controlled by the Graphics card and run with the available Video drivers. Using the Service tag, it should list your installed video card driver there. If not, you can visit the Graphics card support site (either nVidia or ATI). Also - LCD panels don't support an infinite range of sizes. Check your Dell specs for LCD panel model number and then find its supported sizes to verify if 1366x768 is even physically possible.

Comment: I will check graphic card driver again although I believe it's already correctly installed. The reason I think it's display driver issue is because my Lenovo has a "ThinkPad Display 1900x600" driver (10 resolution options) whereas Dell only has "Generic PnP Display" (only 3 options).

Comment: There should be two entries in the windows device manager. One for "Monitors" (where its fine to have a generic PNP monitor) and a second for "Display Adapter". That should be the latest video driver for your laptop, that controls the screen resolution sent to your monitor.

Comment: Checking the specs for this laptop here - http://www.dell.com/us/business/p/latitude-e6420/pd shows that dell sells this with two different LCD options: 1366x768 or 1600x900. So if your display shows 1600x900, you have that LCD. You can't downsize to the smaller 1366 resolution thru software settings. You typically want to use the native resolution of the LCD panel for the best display.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the windows default installation driver (from a new installation of win 7) it shows you a lot more resolutions. I'm thinking of extracting that driver from a clean install on another 6420 of a new user, then bringing it to mine because its annoying not to have more resolutions.

Comment: the custom resolution suggested as an alternate solution does not work on this dell graphics adapter (it is only for nvidia and ati) , the other one does not work on windows 7, so none of them are alternate solutions, this question is really old, and the drivers from dell now properly give the resolutions needed.

Answer (score 0):

Alternate solution: [custom resolution utility](http://www.monitortests.com/forum/Thread-Custom-Resolution-Utility-CRU) or Intel Graphics drivers [custom resolution](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/custom-resolutions-on-intel-graphics) option.